# __doPostBack only works if there is a LinkButton, Calendar or WizardStep control on the page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have identified a problem with __doPostBack and found a work around. I am seeking an explanation for the cause and/or a better solution than my work around.

**Scenario:**
I have a dropdown populated with the values; "-Select-", "One" & "Two". If the user selects "One" than client side script is executed. If the user selects "Two" than server side script is executed.

**Problem:**
The client script initiates the postback by calling __doPostBack. However, no post back actually occurs unless there is also a LinkButton, Calendar or WizardStep control on the page. I actually went through all of the standard tools in the Visual Studio Toolbox and tested them all. It has to be one of those three.

**Work Around:**
Add a link button surrounded by a span with display set to none.

```
<span style="display:none;">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</span>
```

**Question:** Can somebody provide an explanation for this behavior or provide a better fix than my "Work Around"?

**Source - Javascript** (I placed it between the head tags)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function DropDownList1_change(elementRef) {
        var selectedIndex = elementRef.selectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex > 0) {
            var selectedValue = elementRef.options[selectedIndex].value;
            if (selectedValue == "One") {
                alert("Because you selected 'One', special javascript code will be executed");
                // Special javascript code goes here
                return;
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "Two") {
                // Special server code gets executed on server DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged
                __doPostBack('DropDownList1', '');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Source - ASPX Controls**

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  onchange="DropDownList1_change(this)" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>-Select-</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />

    <!-- For some unknown reason __doPostBack only works if there is a LinkButton, Calendar or WizardStep control on the page -->      
    <span style="display:none;">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </span>

    Time of last Post Back: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
    Time of OnSelectedIndexChanged: <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Source - Code Behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

**Additional Resource** - I found the following article after posting this question. Its a very old Microsoft article and the only Microsoft article I found that mentions the specific limitation of DropDowns, return values & postbacks. I haven't digged deep into their solution and not sure time will allow me to. Mainly posting it in case my solution fails down the road or doesn't work for someone else.

> Intuitively you might think adding a confirm dialog box for a
>   DropDownList is identical to adding such a dialog box for a Button Web
>   control. That is, simply set the DropDownList's client-side onchange
>   attribute to something like: return confirm(...);. using:
>   DropDownListID.Attributes("onchange") = "return confirm(...);"
>   Unfortunately, this won't work as desired because an AutoPostBack
>   DropDownList's onchange attribute will be set to a bit of JavaScript
>   that causes a postback, namely a call to the client-side __doPostBack
>   function. When setting the onchange attribute programmatically
>   yourself, the end result is that the rendered client-side onchange
>   event handler has both your code and the call to __doPostBack:

The article is long so search for "Confirmation with AutoPostBack DropDownLists"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx

Comment: Honestly, the best workaround I've got is to not use WebForms. The technology is absolutely awful for doing anything custom in the browser, like what you're doing. If you use WebForms, then in my opinion you should do it 100%, which would mean instead of using `onchange` and executing traditional javascript, handle your `One` scenario inside the postback itself and potentially register custom javascript on the response of that postback.

Comment: Do you observe that behavior in a new project? I tried reproducing the problem (with VS 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0) and the postback is performed every time by selecting an item in the DropDownList.

Comment: I get the same behavior in a new project; I created both an empty new web site and web application project for testing it. I am using VS 2010, .NET Framework 4, windows 7 32 bit & Cassini (will try it from IIS).

Comment: Tried IIS instead of Cassini. Same issue.

Comment: __doPostBack is not supposed to be used directly by client scripts. This is why it has double underscore. Like private private.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

**Solution 1:**
A better [work around](http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/insure-that-dopostback-function-implemented-on-the-page) than adding a link button surrounded by hidden span tags is to add the following to the page load event. This ensures that the function __doPostBack is available.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
}
```

The function `__doPostBack` is generated only if a control in the form needs it to perform postbacks. This includes controls like the LinkButton and other controls for which `AutoPostBack` is set to `true`. In fact, only the Button and ImageButton controls can perform postbacks without `__doPostBack` (see [this article](http://dotnetprof.blogspot.ca/2012/08/dopostback-function-in-javascript.html)). For example, we can see in the HTML output that a LinkButton is rendered this way:

```
<a id="lnk" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;lnk&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">My link</a>
```

---

**Solution 2:** The following approach achieves the same thing without using __doPostBack.

In the present case, you could set `AutoPostBack="true"` for the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" onchange="if (!confirmPostBack(this)) return false;" ... >
```

The `onchange` event handler would return `false` when you want to prevent the postback. The Javascript function could be something like this:

```
function confirmPostBack(ddl)
{
    if (condition) {
        ...
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Important**: The `onchange` event handler should not return anything to allow the postback to occur. You can use this syntax:

```
onchange="if (!confirmPostBack(this)) return false;"
```

For reasons probably explained in the article mentioned in the question, the following syntax does not work. Returning `true` still prevents the postback.

```
onchange="return confirmPostBack(this);" // Does not work!
```

Comment: That was how I first tried. However, returning true/false does not work with javascript initiated by a dropdown. After a button click a postback can be canceled with a return false, however, not with a dropdown. This is a little known limitation on dropdowns. There are some work arounds on the internet. Please don't bother posting any cause I've already tried them all. I really just want to understand why I need to add a LinkButton to make __doPostBack work.

Comment: You say that it doesn't work. But it does work. Tested 100%. The important thing is, if you want the postback to occur, do not return anything, not even `true`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not return anything. The confirmPostBack function you wrote returns either true or false.

Comment: See my note at the end of the answer. As you say, `confirmPostBack` returns `true` or `false` but the `onchange` event handler does not return anything if it is `true`. Also note that I added an explanation for the presence (or absence) of `__doPostBack` in the page.

Comment: I added a workaround which ensures that `__doPostBack` is generated in the rendered page.