# Disable PostBack button asp and run server code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to prevent my asp.net button to do `PostBack` as follow:

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="Confirm(); return false;" />
```

This is prevent button `PostBack` but that's isnt running also my `OnClick` button event.
How can i fix it?
What i'm trying to do is to display confirm message, but if the user click on 'No' the button do `PostBack`

Confirm function:

```
function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
```

My Button callback (that isn't calling while 'return false' append to OnClientClick:

```
public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
    //my code
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnClientClick` event handler should return `false` only when you want to prevent the postback. The simplest way to do it would be:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Do you want to save data?')) return false;" ... />
```

If you need more processing during the confirmation process, you can put it in your Javascript function which should return a boolean value:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="if (!confirmSaving()) return false;" ... />

function confirmSaving() {
    ...
    if (some condition) {
        ...
        return true;
    } else {
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: we could simply return the value of the function instead of putting a condition inside `OnClientClick`. That solution fails for some controls however (see [__doPostBack only works if there is a LinkButton, Calendar or WizardStep control on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750327/dopostback-only-works-if-there-is-a-linkbutton-calendar-or-wizardstep-control/38752312#38752312)), while the conditional version works for all of them.